# How to type and delete for two input fields simultaneously in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple tabs each containing a datagrid with a list of names. Each tab has a 'search' `input` field where a search can be performed for values inside the datagrid. I would like to type a string in the first search input field and see the same string when I change between tabs. Also when I delete the string in the second tab it should delete in the first tab as well.

I managed to copy the string to the second search field where I encountered a few problems.

1. Although the string gets copied to the second search field the search does not apply.
2. If I delete the search string in the second search field the string still remains in the first search field. My goal is to somehow connect the two search fields together and work as one.

```js
$(document).ready(function myFunction() {
  $('#datagridOne').find('.e-input-large').bind('keypress blur', function myFunctionT() {
    $('#datagridTwo').find('.e-input-large').val($('.e-input-large').val() );
  });  
});
```

Comment: How is the search logic triggered?

Comment: Could you instead put the "search box" *outside* the tabs?  Then you only have one input to worry about.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you for your reply .By default the datagrid searches for the given keywords in the visible fields. If there are multiple words, they don't have to be next to each other but all must be present somewhere. If a column uses html, it also searches in the html code. The set of fields that will be examined can be overridden with the search-keys attribute (even not visible fields can be used) and the actual search keyword can be set with the search-keyword attriubte.

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<input class="mySearchFields" type="search">
<input class="mySearchFields" type="search">
```

Jquery:

```
$(".mySearchFields").on("input", function(){
   $(".mySearchFields").val($(this).val());
});
```

Code snippet demonstrating it:

```js
$(".mySearchFields").on("input", function(){
    $(".mySearchFields").val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="mySearchFields" type="search">
<input class="mySearchFields" type="search">
<input class="mySearchFields" type="search">
<input class="mySearchFields" type="search">
<input class="mySearchFields" type="search">
```

Try this

EDIT:
Added more than to search input fields to demonstrate that this solution is not limited to two but can work on all input fields with the same class.

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply, this works however I noticed that the search does not apply. So it copies from one search field to another but it looks like the search is performed on keystroke or if manually copied and pasted in the other search field.

Comment: @ORCos what do you mean "search does not apply"?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it almost simultaneously by using jquery :

```
<input class="one" name="ipt">
<input class="one" name="ipt">
```

JQuery:

```
$(".one").change(function(){
    $('input[name="ipt"]').val($(".one").val());
});
```

Edited: It was just an example to show the concept. Now it is more exact

Comment: Well, yes, but this doesn't solve the main 'searching' issue. This also only works one way, not when you type in to `#two` as the OP requests.

Comment: also.. the input id changes each time i refresh the page(im using an ui kit for the datagrid and I don;t have access to the code behind it). I am able to extract the input class by inspecting the element in devtools

Comment: This will only affect two when one is changed and not the other way around.

Check my answer above using class to remedy this.

Comment: @Zuks this was just to show the concept. Edited to make it more clear

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this was just to show the concept. Edited to make it more clear

Comment: @ORCos changed it from id to class. You can change it to whatever you like! the concept still works!